# How to handle Visual Studio Solutions with projects from different repositories and branches

Tags: svn, branch

Assume we have 2 different SVN repositories, each with trunk and dev branches. CommonRepoA is a common repository used by different departments. RepoB is a repository with solutions also using projects and libraries from CommonRepoA. Given an example directory structure:

- CommonRepoA

  - trunk

    - prod
  - dev

    - myBranch

---

- RepoB

  - trunk

    - prod
  - dev

    - myBranch

We assume that we create a branch from a project in RepoB/trunk/prod to RepoB/dev/myBranch. According to RepoB, we also create a new branch in CommonRepoA with similar directory structure.

Now my question: To complete this branch, we need to update all the references to the projects and libraries to the new branch CommonRepoA/dev/myBranch. RepoB projects reference projects and libraries in CommonRepoA. 
In case of merging between the branches, one needs to take care of the project files to not merge the paths to the other branch. 
Is there any best practice for this process or any plugin to avoid the reference updates that are currently done in manual way by the developers? 
This task is empirically very fault-prone. ;)

Best regards

Comment: Are you using `svn:externals` to include the `CommonReposA` project as a subdirectory of `RepoB`?

Comment: No, we are not using this feature at all.

Comment: If i understand that right, this oppertunity will double the CommonRepoA into every branch in RepoB? Unfortunately we have many branches of RepoB. :( So, this will take much space on the dev-clients.